# Javascript file cause React (Typescript) fail to start

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-typescript

I have a React project with Typescript. One day I create a javascript file in `src/` and then my React app failed to start on localhost. Any explanation about this would be appriciated.
**Evironment**: Node 16.13.1
**Step to reproduce**:

```
git clone git@github.com:manaclan/fun-pms-frontend.git
cd fun-pms-frontend
git checkout vinhngo
```

Inside package.json remove:

```
"@types/react-facebook-login": "^4.1.4"
"react-facebook-login": "^4.1.1"
```

Then `npm install` and `npm start` will notify that localhost:3000 failed to connect. Removing `src/setupProxy.js` will make the server start as normal

Answer (score 1):

That's because JavaScript is not allowed in Typescript projects, you would need to modify your Typescript config, add the following flag to to the config file

--allowJs

Depending on the module bundler you probably also have to set the output directory for the transpiled Typescript files.

Comment: tks for the response but can you provide some reference links about this ?

Comment: Sorry here is some reference https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig/allowJs.html . What exactly is the error? Maybe there is another reason, I  only suggested this, because I also had some issues regarding js inside of ts project and that solved the problem.